# Creating a custom function to populate a Pickerview-Textfield in a TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview, uipickerview

Goal: to get a `UITableView` with dynamic prototype cells that display a label and a textfield with a `pickerview`. The content of the label and the `pickerview` is supplied by an array.

Since I first posted this question I've come a long way. What I have now:

1: The model

```
struct PersonalDetail {
var question: String
var answers: [String]
var answerType: String

init(questions: String, answArray: [String], answType: String){
    self.question = questions
    self.answers = answArray
    self.answerType = answType
}}

var personalDetailArray = [
PersonalDetail(questions: "Country", answArray: ["USA","UK","Germany"], answType: "String"),
PersonalDetail(questions: "Age", answArray: ["10","20","30"], answType: "Int"),
PersonalDetail(questions: "Length", answArray: ["100","200","300"], answType: "Int"),
PersonalDetail(questions: "Weigth", answArray: ["1","2","3"], answType: "Int"),
PersonalDetail(questions: "Education", answArray: ["High School","University","Coder"], answType: "String"),
PersonalDetail(questions: "Number", answArray: ["1","2","3"], answType: "Int")]
```

2: I have the whole set up ready (tableView, tableViewCell, identifier set, outlets connected, etc.). The label is already properly displayed using:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PersonalDetailsQuestion") as! PersonalDetailsTableViewCell
let questionsExtra = personalDetailArray[indexPath.row]
cell.personalDetailQ?.text = questionsExtra.question 
cell.configurePickerView()  //This is not working yet!
```

3: What I want: my function (called: configurePickerView) that can get the content of the pickerview from my personalDetailArray.AnswArray in the model, which I think should look like this:

```
cell.configurePickerView(answAarray: questionsExtra.answers)
```

4: Where I need your help: in the TabelViewCell class I've created a pickerView with a toolbar that works nicely on its own, but I get stuck trying to populate the pickerview dynamically, and preferably stores the input so that I can send it to my database. **What can I do to make it work?** This is what I have so far:

```
class PersonalDetailsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var personDetailA : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var personalDetailQ: UILabel!

internal func configurePickerView(// HOW DO I DEFINE MY INPUT, THE ARRAY?) {
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "nextPicker")
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton, spaceButton, nextButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true


    personDetailA.inputView = pickerView
    personDetailA.placeholder = "Not Set"
    personDetailA.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    if let text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("test") {
        personDetailA.text = text
    }}}

extension PersonalDetailsTableViewCell: UIPickerViewDataSource {

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(colorPicker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return // NEEDS PROPER INPUT
}}

extension PersonalDetailsTableViewCell {

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{return // NEEDS PROPER INPUT
}
func nextPicker() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(personDetailA.text, forKey: "test")
    personDetailA.nextResponder() // HOW DO I GET TO THE NEXT PICKERVIEW?}
func donePicker() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(personDetailA.text, forKey: "test")
    personDetailA.resignFirstResponder() // HOW DO I SAVE THE INPUT DYNAMICALLY?}
}
```